# VBA Call Stored Procedure with Parameters Using ADO

Tags: vba, stored-procedures, ado

I'm trying to call a SQL Server stored procedure with two parameters in VBA using ADO; however I got error message "Run-time error '13' Type mismatch". I've spent hours searching on online but just can't get it working...
Here is my code:

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;" _
                 & "Server=(Local);" _
                 & "Database=Inventory;" _
                 & "Integrated Security=SSPI;" _
                 & "DataTypeCompatibility=80;"
cnn.Open

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = "adCmdText"
    .CommandText = "usp_mySP"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@fileName1", adChar, adParamInput, , File1.Name)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@fileName2", adChar, adParamInput, , File2.Name)
    .Execute
End With
```

The `File1.Name` and `File2.Name` are names of two latest-modified files that I got using FileSystemObject.

The `usp_mySP` is my stored procedure that essentially uses bcp command to export a tab-delimited file. It works perfectly fine in SQL Sever.

Any advice or comments?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@` characters from the param names? `adVarChar`? Also, not directly related, but you most certainly do not want to declare these object `As New`.

Comment: @Mat's I think I know why, I shouldn't add quotes around `adCmdText`

Comment: Oh, right. That's an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After another couple hours of trial and error I finally get the code working. And thanks @Mat's for pointing out to change `adChar` to `adVarChar`.

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;" _
             & "Server=(Local);" _
             & "Database=Inventory;" _
             & "Integrated Security=SSPI;" _
             & "DataTypeCompatibility=80;"
cnn.Open

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "usp_mySP"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@fileName1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, File1.Name)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@fileName2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, File2.Name)
    .Execute
End With
MsgBox"Thank God! Finally it's working!"
cnn.Close
```